# Bitbake LibSocketCAN

Tags: embedded, yocto, bitbake, socketcan

I am trying to build `libsocketcan` into my image. To add `libsocketcan` In my main application recipe I added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " libsocketcan "`. When debugging my application with Eclipse this works perfectly. When I attempt to bitbake my application I am told

```
fatal error: libsocketcan.h: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure where I am missing my dependency.
Makefile.am

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign subdir-objects

bin_PROGRAMS = MAIN_Application

MAIN_Application_LDADD = -lsocketcan -lpthread

AM_CPPFLAGS = \
-I$(srcdir)/include \
-I$(srcdir)/include/utilities \
-I$(srcdir)/include/comms

MAIN_Application_SOURCES = \
src/main.c \
src/scheduler.c \
src/utilities/time_conversions.c \
src/utilities/ring_buffer.c \
src/utilities/logger.c \
src/comms/can.c
```

I believe this is the only file that would make a difference. Has anyone else ever faced this? What else do I need to do to allow my bitbake to find the include?

Edit: recipe as requestes

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
IMAGE_LINGUAS = " "

# Base image Install
IMAGE_INSTALL = " packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL}"

# Configure image base size
IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE ?= "4096"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE_append = "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "systemd", " + 2048", "", d)}"

# User preferences 
inherit core-image
inherit extrausers

# Change root password (note the capital -P)
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
  usermod -P toor  root; \
  useradd -P michael -G sudo  michael; \
  "

# uncomment the line %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL in /etc/sudoers
modify_sudoers() {
    sed 's/# %sudo/%sudo/' < ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers.tmp
    mv ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers.tmp ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND_append = " modify_sudoers;"

# Dependencies
DEPENDS = " libsocketcan "

# Install necessary libraries
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " can-utils "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " libsocketcan"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " sudo "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " iw wireless-tools wpa-supplicant "

# Install SMG applications
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " udevrules "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " mainapplication "

# Apply kernel customizations
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://kernel_customization.cfg"

# Remove image features
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += " packagegroup-fsl-optee-imx"
BAD_RECOMMENDATIONS = " udev-hwdb" 

#MKUBIFS_ARGS="--leb-size 126976 --min-io-size 2048 --max-leb-cnt 3600"
#UBINIZE_ARGS="--peb-size 128KiB --min-io-size 2048 --sub-page-size 2048"
#IMAGE_FSTYPES += " ubi ubifs"
```

Edit 2: main application recipe

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "\
    file://MAIN_Application \
        file://services \   
    "

inherit autotools systemd

S = "${WORKDIR}/MAIN_Application"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "MAINapplication.service"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/services/MAINapplication.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/MAINapplication.service
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libsocketcan` provides these packages:

```
tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libsocketcan/0.0.11-r0/image
└── usr
    ├── include
    │   ├── can_netlink.h
    │   └── libsocketcan.h
    ├── lib
    │   ├── libsocketcan.so -> libsocketcan.so.2.3.0
    │   ├── libsocketcan.so.2 -> libsocketcan.so.2.3.0
    │   ├── libsocketcan.so.2.3.0
    │   └── pkgconfig
    │       └── libsocketcan.pc
```

Adding `DEPENDS += "libsocketcan"` will cause all those files to be populated into your custom layer's working directory.

**NOTE**
Your recipe seems to do not install your `MAIN_Application` output binary file. So your recipe should look like:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "\
    file://MAIN_Application \
        file://services \   
    "

inherit autotools systemd

S = "${WORKDIR}/MAIN_Application"

DEPENDS += "libsocketcan"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "MAINapplication.service"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/services/MAINapplication.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/MAINapplication.service
    install -m 0644 ${S}/MAIN_Application ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Just make sure that `MAIN_Application` is the right binary name.

Answer (score 1):

IMAGE_INSTALL_append adds package to image.

It has not much to do with build-time dependencies of your application.

What you should add to you app.bb is:

DEPENDS = "libsocketcan"

Comment: I added the depends line. I get the same error.

Comment: Please provide the full recipe.

Comment: Posted the recipe as requested

Comment: You posted the image recipe, please post the recipe of the software that has the Makefile

Comment: Posted, I use autotools, makefile.am and configure.ac.

Comment: I added the depends to my main application recipe and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer just to help you fix some issues related to your image recipe:

Here are some important comment:

- **IMAGE_INSTALL**

```
IMAGE_INSTALL = " packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL}"
...
inherit core-image
```

Never and never override `IMAGE_INSTALL` before `core-image`, because `IMAGE_INSTALL` of `core-image` will not take effect.

- **Variable assignement**

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " can-utils "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " libsocketcan"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " sudo "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " iw wireless-tools wpa-supplicant "
```

Do not use `append` with `+=` , use one of them only.

- **DEPENDS ??**
  Image recipes are just dedicated to collect recipes and create image rootfs and final image type (wic, ...)
  You do not need `DEPENDS`.
- **SRC_URI ??**
  This is also a non-image recipe variable, did it even took effect ?
  Move the kernel configuration fragment to your custom `virtual/kernel` package recipe.

I recommend your image recipe to look like:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
IMAGE_LINGUAS = " "

# Configure image base size
IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE ?= "4096"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE_append = "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "systemd", " + 2048", "", d)}"

# User preferences 
inherit core-image extrausers

# Change root password (note the capital -P)
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
  usermod -P toor  root; \
  useradd -P michael -G sudo  michael; \
  "

# uncomment the line %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL in /etc/sudoers
modify_sudoers() {
    sed 's/# %sudo/%sudo/' < ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers.tmp
    mv ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers.tmp ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sudoers
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND_append = " modify_sudoers;"

# Install necessary libraries
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh \
            can-utils \
            libsocketcan \
            sudo \
            iw wireless-tools wpa-supplicant"

# Install SMG applications
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " udevrules \
            mainapplication"

# Remove image features
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += " packagegroup-fsl-optee-imx"
BAD_RECOMMENDATIONS = " udev-hwdb" 

#MKUBIFS_ARGS="--leb-size 126976 --min-io-size 2048 --max-leb-cnt 3600"
#UBINIZE_ARGS="--peb-size 128KiB --min-io-size 2048 --sub-page-size 2048"
#IMAGE_FSTYPES += " ubi ubifs"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am new to bitbake and Yocto. It has been a journey to get here and I really appreciate the help in cleaning up my recipe!

Comment: A note, the SRC_URI did take effect and applied the kernel changes

Comment: I have a question about this. I am trying to install my image without bluetooth, alsa, PCI etc. Removing IMAGE_INSTALL = " packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL}" adds these back. What is the correct way to remove these?

Comment: `core-image` integrates extra packagegroups based on some distro features, so check `DISTRO_FEATURES` with ``bitbake -e | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES=` and remove bluetooth or any feature you don't desire.

Comment: If I remove that line from my bb file I get errors stating that moal_pcie.h:133:20: error: array type has incomplete element type 'struct msix_entry' I have no idea where this is from.

Comment: This is a different issue and out of this question topic, if this is a real issue for you, create a new question and I will have a look.

Comment: I do not think it is. You mentioned that my IMAGE_INSTALL will override the core image. I think this is ok because the core image from NXP has more than I want. With this line in my recipe I have a small working image.

Comment: I recommend that you read about DISTRO_FEATURES and MACHINE_FEATURES and from that you will know exactly what you need to add/remove, it is just a matter of knowing the Yocto features for your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243333/discussion-between-michael-and-talel-belhadjsalem).